# Test suite failed to run TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to setup Jest on my react-native project but it hasn't been playing nice with [bugsnag-react-native](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native).

With my current test configuration I'm seeing errors related to bugsnag's `leaveBreadcrumb` function seen below:

```
 FAIL  app/__tests__/NetworkReducer.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (app/__tests__/NetworkReducer.test.js:10:20)
          at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
          at Promise (<anonymous>)
```

I have a helper file that instantiates bugsnag:

```
helpers/bugSnag.js


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create a single instance of the bugsnag client so we don't have to duplicate our configuration
// anywhere.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/#basic-configuration

import { Client, Configuration } from 'bugsnag-react-native';
const config = new Configuration();
config.consoleBreadcrumbsEnabled = true;
config.notifyReleaseStages = ['testflight', 'production'];

const bugSnag = new Client(config);


export default bugSnag;
```

So in all my files I'm importing bugSnag from this helper file rather than declaring a new Client in each file, notably in my `NetworkReducer.js` where `bugSnag.leaveBreadcrumb('someData')` is causing me issues.

In my `NetworkReducer.test.js` I'm calling a mock:

```
 jest.mock(bugSnag, () => {
    return {
        leaveBreadcrumb: jest.fn()
    };
 });
```

where I'm also importing `bugSnag from path/to/helpers/bugSnag`

If I comment out the mock, I get a different error message on each of my reducer types that have a `bugSnag.leaveBreadcrumb('someData')` as seen below:

```
TypeError: _bugSnag2.default.leaveBreadcrumb is not a function

  at Object.network_prop_update (app/reducers/NetworkReducer.js:29:19)
  at app/reducers/createReducer.js:4:29
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/__tests__/NetworkReducer.test.js:80:29)
  at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
  at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
  at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
```

I thought I had a handle on this jest thing, and mocking,  but I guess I've been proven wrong. I've attached my Jest's `setup.js` for extra reference:

```
    jest.mock('Linking', () => {
    return {
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
        openURL: jest.fn(),
        canOpenURL: jest.fn(),
        getInitialURL: jest.fn(),
    };
});


jest.mock('PushNotificationIOS', () => {
    return {
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        requestPermissions: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
        getInitialNotification: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    };
});


jest.mock('react-native-intercom', () => {
    return {
        registerIdentifiedUser: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        registerUnidentifiedUser: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        updateUser: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        reset: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        logEvent: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        handlePushMessage: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        displayMessenger: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        hideMessenger: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        displayMessageComposer: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        displayMessageComposerWithInitialMessage: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        displayConversationsList: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        getUnreadConversationCount: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        setLauncherVisibility: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        setInAppMessageVisibility: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        setupAPN: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        registerForPush: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        setUserHash: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        setBottomPadding: jest.genMockFn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        removeEventListener: jest.fn()
    };
});


jest.mock('bugsnag-react-native', () => {
    return {
        leaveBreadcrumb: jest.fn(),
        Configuration: jest.fn(),
        Client: jest.fn()
    };
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution was to add the following mock instead:

```
jest.mock('../app/helpers/bugSnag', () => {
    return {
        leaveBreadcrumb: jest.fn(),
    };
});
```

A clear explanation to all this would be helpful.

Comment: Ah, of course. I should have thought of this. With jest, you want to mock the ES6 module that you import from. So, if you're importing from a library, you say `import x from 'dep'` and thus mock with `jest.mock('dep', () => {})`, but since `bugSnag` is a local file, you import it via its path and mock the same.

Answer (score 19):

This was already answered, but in my case I had a different problem.
Apparently `react-test-renderer` fails to instantiate Components if they are missing their constructor.

So I needed to add them following line to my `PureComponent`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! For the records, version `16.8.4` of `react-test-renderer` works fine!

Comment: @pietro909 are you sure? just tested it with `16.8.4`... I still get the same behavior if I delete the constructor

Comment: @SamerMurad my coworker just ran into the same issue using that version... while "on my machine is working" :-)
We are investigating on it right now, though you are right: that is not the right solution.

Comment: I've just added a different solution which we tested and is working well.

Answer (score 5):

although there's already an accepted answer, I solved it in a different way today.

Following [this answer on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22437#issuecomment-445898652), I put:

`sed -i -- 's/inlineRequires: true,/inlineRequires: false,/' node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js`

In my `postinstall` script. I hope the relevant issue on Github will be solved, but for now, for our team is working like that :-)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for sure @MattyK14

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply moving my class vars into the constructor. Even if I had constructors I still got this error, so moving them into the constructor got rid of the error. Also found that here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22437#issuecomment-445898652